# Nouns that don't require a measure word

Tags: grammar, number, measure-word

Some of the time nouns don't require measure words.

三年，四周，五天，六秒，七日 ...

Are there any more nouns (time nouns or otherwise) that don't require a MW ?

Is there a comprehensive list somewhere ?

Comment: Anything that can be used as a measure word can be situationally interpreted as a noun that doesn't require a measure word, e.g. 里, 升, 杯 (A:`你喝了幾杯水？` B:`五杯!` Not: `五個杯子!`)...

Comment: To some extent, i think 年，周，秒，天等等 are measure word

Answer (score 3):

The trick is the omission behind (again).
It is the **objective** that is omitted, not the MW words.

The complete words are:
 
`三年(时间)`,`四周(时间)`, etc

As you can see now, there are MW words. Just too obvious to add the objective again.

Another example, after business dinner in CN, people usually ask `刚喝了几杯`, 
 which means `几杯(酒)`. But we never say `几酒`.

Comment: Right, agree. For the question, I guess there's no such list of nouns that don't require measure word? I couldn't think of any.

Comment: Yup, I think so. Check more detail for this [MW Chinese explanation](http://tiny.cc/rnnjhz). The main difference of MW in cn is that we use it for countable nouns and actions.

Answer (score 1):

合球隊有四男四女。 In English: There are four males and four females in [Korfball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korfball) team.

他昨天那場打得很好，12殺1死8助攻。 In English: He played well in that round, he got 12 kills 1 death and 8 assists yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I want to say that 年，月，日，周,时，分，秒 they are do units of time,that is certainly measure word. Although they are also nouns.We can call them nominal measure words.

Comment: 月 doesn't count, it requires a measure word!